# Can I use CSS calc within Javascript?

Tags: javascript, css, css-calc

Can I use the css `calc()` function when setting positions in JavaScript?

```
ePopup.style.top = "calc(100px - 1.5em)";
```

Comment: I have of course tried this, it didn't seem to work.  Did it not work because I have done something syntatically incorrect or because it intrinsically does not work.

Comment: @JakeWilson - your edit a few years ago obscured the typo that caused the OP's problem. The post originally showed a ; at the end of the CSS string (within the quotes), which fails leaving the property blank. I made the same blunder and found this. But now it's not clear at all why the OP's code failed.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

Yes, `calc()` will work when setting styles in javascript.

**Working Example:**

```js
var innerDiv = document.getElementsByClassName('inner-div')[0];

function growInnerDiv() {
    innerDiv.style.setProperty('width', 'calc(100% + 224px)');
}

innerDiv.addEventListener('click', growInnerDiv, false);
```

```css
.outer-div {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 200px;
    height: 100px;
    padding: 12px;
    border: 1px solid rgb(255,0,0);
    background-color: rgb(255,255,0);
}

.inner-div {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 100px;
    font-family: arial, helvetica, sans-serif;
    background-color: rgb(255,0,0);
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: all 0.5s linear;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer-div">
    <div class="inner-div">Click Me</div>
<div>
```

Comment: That is good to know that calc can work from Javascript, I will therefore persist with trying to make that work on my page that rather than giving-up and trying alternative methods.

Many thanks for that answer despite the question getting seven down marks.

Comment: You're most welcome, @NickC. I thought your question entirely fair - when a process is not working, it is vital to isolate the component of that process that isn't working, rather than making assumptions - so I gave your question an upvote.

Comment: Yes, @FlorianB, when writing `calc()` functions in CSS, you **must** surround the operator with spaces.

Comment: Does it mean every CSS function can be used this way?

Comment: Yes, @dudung - other CSS functions like `min()`, `max()`, `clamp()` etc. all represent dynamic CSS values which may be applied via JavaScript. For the full list of CSS functions, see: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Functions

Answer (score 5):

There are some interesting things that happen when you use `calc` with the same type of units, e.g. `10px + 5px`. It gets simplified to `15px` by the process that puts it onto the element.

So, to expand on [rounin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3897775/rounin)'s great answer, here's some examples of that behaviour in action:

```js
function growDiv(e) {
        const thisDiv = e.target;
        const x = 100;
        const y = 42;
        const z = 69;
        let widthVal;

        if (thisDiv.id == "simplifies") {
          widthVal = `calc(${y + z}px + ${x}px + ${y}px)`;
        } else if (thisDiv.id == "mixed-units") {
          widthVal = `calc(0em + ${y + z}px + ${x * 2}px + ${y}px)`;
        } else if (thisDiv.id == "variables") {
          thisDiv.style.setProperty("--x", x + "px");
          thisDiv.style.setProperty("--y", y + "px");
          thisDiv.style.setProperty("--z", z + "px");
          widthVal = "calc((var(--x) * 2) + var(--y) + (var(--z) * 2))";
        }

        thisDiv.style.width = widthVal;
        thisDiv.innerHTML =
          `input: ${widthVal}<br>style:${thisDiv.style.width}`;
      }

      document
        .querySelectorAll("div")
        .forEach((el) => el.addEventListener("click", growDiv, false));
```

```css
.inner-div {
        background-color: hotpink;
        color: white;
        font-weight: bold;
        height: 100px;
        margin-bottom: 5px;
        text-align: center;
        transition: all 0.5s linear;
        width: 100px;
      }
```

```html
<div class="inner-div" id="simplifies">simplifies<br />1) Click Me</div>
<div class="inner-div" id="mixed-units">mixed-units<br />2) Click Me</div>
<div class="inner-div" id="variables">variables<br />3) Click Me</div>
```

Div 1 has all the same units, and therefore simplifies.

Div 2 has a token `0em` unit, which makes no difference to the calculation, but forces the full expression to come through.

Div 3 is my favourite because it's a little bit self-documenting. I do this because I'm a bit forgetful and it lets me see *why* I set that element to 728.3 high, not just *that* I did.

Comment: This explains why something which is simple is better as compared to something which is complicated but the runtime makes it work