# Using CSS calc() in JavaScript with a variable

Tags: javascript, css

User NickC asks [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40871127/can-i-use-css-calc-withing-javascript) if it is possible to set an element's position (or similar style properties) in js using CSS's calc() function.

Example:

```
var pad = "calc(1250px - 1000px)";
element.style.paddingLeft = pad;
```

This shows up just fine on my web page, but I would like to include a js variable in the function, like so:

```
var pad = "calc("+ width +"- 1000px)";
alert(pad); //displays calc( 1250px - 1000px)
element.style.paddingLeft = pad;
```

I included the alert statement to assure myself that the string itself was correct, which it appears to be. However, the desired padding does not appear.

Is there a problem with what I'm doing, or is it just not possible to do this?

Comment: So long as the string you end up with is a valid `calc()` expression, it's literally impossible for the browser to tell the difference. Are you sure that the value of `width` includes the "px" suffix?

Comment: why use calc when it is a simple px subtraction?

Comment: @Pointy as long as the `alert(pad)` line isn't lying to me then yeah, I'm sure!

Comment: @epascarello I know I can do that, but it just seemed curious to me that the way I'm trying didn't work.

Comment: It does not work because what is in the alert is not what you have... ;)

Comment: @epascarello could you please explain what I have then?

Comment: I did below. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem you have is a simple issue with a missing  character. Without it, there is no padding, with it there is.

```js
var width = '100px'


var element1 = document.getElementById("test1")
var element2 = document.getElementById("test2")

var pad1 = "calc(" + width + "- 90px)";  //what you have
var pad2 = "calc(" + width + " - 90px)"; //what it should be

element1.style.paddingLeft = pad1;
element2.style.paddingLeft = pad2;
```

```css
div {
  background-color: red
}
```

```html
<div id="test1">
  Hello 1
</div>
<div id="test2">
  Hello 2
</div>
<div>
  Hello d
</div>
```

Comment: Aha! Perfect, that fixed it right up! I had no idea that made a difference, thanks a million!

Comment: So the CSS `calc()` parser doesn't treat the hyphen character as a token? (?!?)

Comment: @pointy - CSS `calc()` [annoyingly/confusingly] requires a space between all operators (`+ \ * -`)

Comment: @RichWerden I guess that's what happens when you jam an alien syntax into an existing grammar :)

Comment: Sadly, I've made the mistake and created that bug more than once.

Comment: According to the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc) you need a space before and after the `+` and `-` operators, however `The * and / operators do not require whitespace, but adding it for consistency is both allowed and recommended.`

Answer (score 2):

```
var pad = `calc(${width} - 90px)`
```

This should also work.

Answer (score 0):

I finally got it, or so I thought:

```
window.onload = function() { resize(); }
window.onresize = function() { resize(); }

function resize() {
if (window.innerWidth >= 992){
    var H = window.innerHeight;
    H = H  - 250;
    H = H + "px";
    document.getElementById('article').style.minHeight =  H;
}
else if (window.innerWidth >= 768 && window.innerWidth <= 991){
    
    var H = window.innerHeight;
    H = H  - 237;
    H = H + "px";
    document.getElementById('article').style.minHeight =  H;  
}
else if (window.innerWidth >= 480 && window.innerWidth <= 767){
   
    var H = window.innerHeight;
    H = H  - 217;
    H = H + "px";
    document.getElementById('article').style.minHeight =  H; 
}
else if (window.innerWidth <= 479){
    
    var H = window.innerHeight;
    H = H  - 201;
    H = H + "px";
    document.getElementById('article').style.minHeight =  H; 
}
}
```

What I don't understand is why the footer on the phone is so far above the bottom of the page. I thought that javascript's window.innerHeight was supposed to get around the 100vh bug in CSS. what am I missing? It's almost as if I swapped one bug for another.

Comment: See this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52848856/100vh-height-when-address-bar-is-shown-chrome-mobile) for an explanation of the footer issue (and the whole 100vh vs 100% debate).