# Sizing main viewport for firefox mobile

Tags: html, css, firefox, mobile, browser

I've been looking for a way to size the main viewport in mobile to accommodate for the navigation bar at the bottom of the page. I want all the content to be visible in between the top of the page and the top of the navigation bar ([CSS3 100vh not constant in mobile browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37112218/css3-100vh-not-constant-in-mobile-browser))

This code works for me in all desktop browsers, and all mobile browsers except for firefox

```
      html,
      body {
        height: 100%;
      }
      #hero {
        height: calc(100vh - calc(100vh - 100%));
        background-color: aqua;
      }
```

How come I'm getting different behaviour in firefox mobile? Thanks for looking

Comment: Does this answer your question? [100vh height when address bar is shown - Chrome Mobile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52848856/100vh-height-when-address-bar-is-shown-chrome-mobile)

Comment: What is your HTML main structure and the css that goes along with it ? what method do you use to lay ... your layout ? grid/flex/position, else ? there might option that won't need to use cal() nor 100vh ...

Answer (score 0):

while awaiting for clarification, here is a sample/template that could do what you look for via grid *(it could be flex if you feel more confident with it).*

```css
html,
body,
body > div {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}
body > div {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr auto;
}
nav {
  background: blue;
  padding: 1em;
  order: 1;
}
main {
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <nav>At the bottom , of any height.</nav>
  <main> let me scroll if too <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>...<br><br><br><br><br><br><br>....<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>....<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>....<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>....<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>....short</main>
</div>
```