# Infamous height:100% issue on chrome for android - address bar

Tags: android, css, viewport, address-bar, google-chrome-android

I have created an angular app where the sidebar is `height: 100%`. However when viewing the webapp in Chrome for Android, when scrolling the document:

1. The chrome address bar slides up gently
2. The 100% real size remains the same until you TouchEnd

[image: height 100 remains until scrolling is finished]

[The darkgrey sidebar](https://github.com/MintPlayer/MintPlayer/blob/master/MP.Web/ClientApp/src/app/app.component.scss#L67) is `height: calc(100%  - 55px)` so the top bar should normally always remain visible, and always fill the remaining space between the top bar and the very bottom.

I've already tried several things to get this fixed. The footer has `bottom: 0` and this one is in fact always rendered correctly. So this made me try to use `top: 55px; bottom: 0` instead of `height: calc(100% - 55px)`. But from the moment you're setting both `top` and `bottom`, the result is the same as setting the height.

Does anybody know a way to make the viewport adjust its height while the address bar is appearing/disappearing?

Comment: Have you tried using `100vh` instead of `100%` for the height?

Comment: Yes I have, but then the sidebar is hidden behind the android back/home/active apps button bar. So the bottom 50px is hidden from view and inaccessible.

Comment: I also tried using `min-height: -webkit-fill-available;` but this makes the user-experience even more horrible...

Comment: `vh` operates the same regardless of whether the address bar is shown or not: https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/12/url-bar-resizing. So it's not `vh` for sure...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I was able to solve this issue by

Creating a css variable (variables.scss)

```
:root {
  --viewport-height: 100%;
}
```

Instead of using `100%` use `var(--viewport-height)`

```
height: calc(100% - 55px);
```

becomes

```
height: calc(var(--viewport-height) - 55px);
```

Then binding to the `visualViewport.resize` event (MUST use `addEventListener` here)

```
if (!serverSide) {
  visualViewport.addEventListener('resize', () => {
    document.documentElement.style.setProperty('--viewport-height', `${visualViewport.height}px`);
  });
}
```

Make sure there is no transition set for the height property.

CSS variables are supported by [all major browsers](https://caniuse.com/css-variables).

- [VisualViewport docs](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/09/visual-viewport-api)
- Linked-from-docs [Demo](https://bokand.github.io/demo/urlbarsize.html) with [source code](http://view-source:https://bokand.github.io/demo/urlbarsize.html)
- [Commit reference](https://github.com/MintPlayer/MintPlayer/commit/2e977ece6fd0bb6cd7d2bb0ef687d9121f778c68)

Comment: Please explain `55px`

Comment: Yes, that's the height of my header. The sidebar fills the space between the header and the bottom of the window

Comment: I have to add however that this does work with the address bar, but doesn't work for the tabstrip that's shown when you have multiple tabs in the same tabgroup. The visualViewport.height doesn't seem to take this tabstrip into account.

Comment: Amazing answer!

Comment: Just as a note, if you also add `document.documentElement.style.setProperty('--viewport-height', `${visualViewport.height}px`);` before the `addEventListener`, it will adjust properly when the website is loaded (else, it would only adjust properly when the user resizes it)