# Insert Javascript variable in CSS calc() function

Tags: javascript, css

I've got a JS variable representing a width in pixels that I'd like to use inside a CSS calc() function.

*The variable is holding the width of a div's scrollbar.*

```
let table = document.getElementById("RGtable");

let offsetWidth = RGtable.offsetWidth;
let clientWidth = RGtable.clientWidth;

function getScrollbarWidth() {
  return offsetWidth - clientWidth;
};

let scrollbarWidth = getScrollbarWidth() + "px";

let header = document.getElementById("tableHeader");

// This is where I have the problem
header.style.setProperty('width', 'calc(100% - scrollbarWidth)');
```

I've tried:

```
header.style.setProperty('width', 'calc(100% - 'getScrollbarWidth() + 'px'')');
```

which gives me errors, and

```
header.style.setProperty('width', 'calc(100% -  ${width})')
```

which is based off of [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45084227/using-css-calc-in-javascript-with-a-variable).

I know I'm missing something, just can't figure out what!

Comment: `'calc(100% - 'getScrollbarWidth()` is missing the `+` in between: `'calc(100% - ' + getScrollbarWidth()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to properly interpolate the string:

with backticks (*not* single quotes)

```
header.style.setProperty('width', `calc(100% - ${scrollbarWidth})`);
```

or with string concatenation

```
header.style.setProperty('width', 'calc(100% - ' + scrollbarWidth + ')');
```

Comment: Ahh right, I see where I was going wrong. Thanks so much!