# How can I set an element's position with Javascript if this position uses the calc() function?

Tags: javascript, styles

This works as expected:

```
document.getElementById('blah').style.left = '200px';
```

However, this refuses to work for reasons unknown to me:

```
document.getElementById('blah').style.left = 'calc(225px-25px)';
```

No errors in the console. The property simply seems not to be set.

Why? And how to make this work?

Comment: And why don't you set it to 25px? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40871127/can-i-use-css-calc-withing-javascript

Comment: I mean instead of using `calc(225px-220px)` use: `20px`directly. It doesn't make sense. calc is more for percentages.

Comment: @Ikillnukes Sure but this is meat to be minimal example of a failing code aimed to be as simple as possible and not to make any actual sense. Besides in my particular use case I have one of these values in a variable so using `calc` saves me one `toString()` and one `parseInt()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that when using `calc` with `+` and `-` operators you must always wrap the operator with whitespce on both sides:

```
calc(225px - 25px)
```

This will work for you:

```
document.getElementById('blah').style.left = 'calc(225px - 25px)';
```